# Declaration "ERC721" not found in "c:/Users/

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js, javascript, hardhat

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

import {ERC721} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol"; // i get error in this line
import {ERC721} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract RealEstate is ERC721URIStorage{

}
```

this output i got from vscode

Declaration "ERC721" not found in "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol" (referenced as "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol").

Declaration "ERC721" not found in "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol" (referenced as "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol").

Declaration "ERC721" not found in "c:/Users/(user)/millow/node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol" (referenced as "c:/Users/(user)/millow/node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol").

Comment: Is it a compilation error or just a VS code error? Try compiling once, coz VS code sometimes shows useless errors.

Comment: this ouput from vscode
DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
  --> contracts/RealEstate.sol:11:24:
   |
11 | contract RealEstate is ERC721URIStorage{
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^